# On resizing browser menu icons change it's position

Tags: css, resize

Here : http://thunderstorm999.byethost9.com/

On resizing browser, menu icons on the top right position change it's position. If I resize the browser towards left then the top right menu icons shifts to left wherease i need the icons to be at the absolute position on the top right itself. It has to be static. I used absolute position to share class but then the icons shifts absolutely to left and then i have to give more than 1000px of margin left inorder to pull it to left. i

```css
body{
margin:36px;
}
.logo{
float:left;
padding-left:100px;
}
.share{
list-style:none;

}
.share li{
display:inline;
float:right;
}
.share img{
margin-right:20px;
}
aside{
position:relative;
}
.navigation{
float:left;
list-style:none;
position:absolute;
text-align:center;
}
.navigation img{
margin-left:-30px;
margin-top: 30px;
}
.social{

position:relative;

}
.social_icons{
text-align:center;
position:absolute;
list-style:none;
top:480px;
left:-10px;
}
.social img{
margin-bottom:10px;
}

.main{
position:relative;
display:block;
padding:0;
}
.main-image{
position:absolute;
margin-left:100px;
margin-top:40px;
padding:0;
border-left:1px dotted red;
border-bottom:1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Speck</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<div class="logo">
<img src="images\logo.png"/>
</div>
<ul class="share">
<li><img class="image1" src="images\fade.png"/></li>
<li><img class="image2" src="images\cart.png"/></li>
<li><img class="image3" src="images\share.png"/></li>
</ul>
</header>
<aside>
<ul class="navigation">
<li><a href="#"><img id="image1" src="images\explore.png"/></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images\material.png"/></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images\team.png"/></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images\contact.png"/></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images\merchandise.png"/></a></li>
</ul>
</aside>
<aside class="social">
<ul class="social_icons">
<li><a href="#"><img id="image1" src="images\fb.png"/></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images\vimeo.png"/></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="images\linkedin.png"/></a></li>
</ul>
</aside>
<section class="main">
<div class="main-image">
<img class="image1" src="images/slides/circus-aerial-act.jpg" style="display: block;">
</div>
</section>
<footer>
</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

is there any better option? Please tell me where am I going wrong. I have used  class 'share' in the html. Please follow the link above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a fixed width on the share class and it will work:

```
.share {
    list-style: none;
    width: 1000px; // Example
}
```

Comment: I tried with the above solution.The logo is proper but then the right menu icons are still shifting to the left.

Comment: My bad, I did not understand it that way. Put a fixed width on the share class and your icons will stop moving.

Comment: I edited it. Still not working.
http://thunderstorm999.byethost9.com/
Check the style on this page.

Comment: I do have one more issue.. regarding the border.can you give me your email id or a link where we can chat on an issue. 
you may add me on : thunderstorm999@gmail.com